# How can I avoid new lines when adding to a text file from a batch program

Tags: batch-file

I am writing this batch program, that writes to a text file to store data that will be used later on. The thing is when I recall my data it only takes the last line of the text file. The problem is that every time I add data it adds the data on a new line, so I only get the last input back. Is there a way that I can add data to a text document, without adding it on a new line?

Comment: Did I format it correctly? Sorry this is my first question.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the batch ?

Comment: ***Show Code***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection doesn't matter at all. You can suppress the line break the same way you would when writing to the screen via `set /p`:

```
< nul >> foo.txt set /p _=Some text.
```

`echo` will of course always add a line break after the written line.